# How can I pretty-print a well-formed invalid XML snippet in java?

Tags: java, xml, sax

I've tried

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
factory.setValidating(false);
XMLReader reader = factory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
Source xmlInput = new SAXSource(reader, new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
xmlPretty = new StreamResult(stringWriter);   
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlPretty);
return xmlPretty.getWriter().toString();
```

but as soon as there is an "ignorable space" the indentation stops. I've searched a lot but found nothing about ignorable spaces in sax parsers, except in Handlers. So I've tried to add a handler of mine:

```
class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
  @Override
  public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("foo");
  }
}
...
reader.setContentHandler(new MyHandler());
```

but it never prints "foo".

Update:
Here is an example of input:

```
<n:a>  <b>foo </b>  </n:a>
```

So well-formed but invalid (n is not defined). I want the function to output something like:

```
<n:a>
  <b>foo </b>
</n:a>
```

The program above does output this if I provide it with:

```
<n:a><b>foo </b></n:a>
```

But not with `<n:a>  <b>foo </b>  </n:a>`.

Comment: Show sample input, output, and desired output.

Comment: I've written a pretty-printer libs which natively supports existing whitespace: https://github.com/greenbird/xml-formatter-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the namespace not declared makes any difference, while additional whitespaces do. 
I tried your code and, I'm still trying to understand why, if you add this line

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
```

you should have the desired output. Could you confirm this and check for any eventual side effects?

Comment: Having the namespace not declared doesn't make any direct difference but it means I cannot use the DocumentBuilderFactorys's setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace method because it assumes validation is on. Anyway, I would prefer to use SAX here: no need to build an intermediate representation. Trying you suggestion in a sec..

Comment: So it does work indeed, but not with `<a>  <b></b></a>` for instance. I suppose that's because `a` and `b` are valid HTML tags. I suspect it works otherwise because it implicitly sets a DTD, and the documentation seems to indicate that when there's a DTD ignorable space is ignored. I thought I would require to enable validation. So maybe if I setup an empty DTD...

Comment: Maybe not after all, HTML is another output method.

Comment: Yeah, of course, the namespace not declared makes a lot of difference when you try to parse as xml. I meant with your actual code, the result seems the same with valid xml or not. The html output method it's more a hack than a real solution, if you think it isn't useful I will delete my answer.

Comment: Yes, it is useful but as you said it is a hack. That's the most useful answer so far anyway.